# Change values of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, loops, matrix

I need to get the upper triangle of a matrix by setting everything under the diagonal to 0.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<vector <int>> upper_triangle(vector<vector <int>> n) {
    int rij = n.size();
    int kolom = n.size();
    vector<vector<int>> result = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < rij; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < kolom; j++) {
            if (i > j) {
                result[i][j] = 0;
            }


        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The output that I get is simply the matrix itself which is not what I need.

```
{{10,11,12},{13,14,15},{16,17,18}}
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

The output I need would be:

```
{{10,11,12},{0,14,15},{0,0,18}}
{{1,2,3},{0,5,6},{0,0,9}}
{{1,2},{0,4}}
```

Comment: You need to pass `std::vector<std::vector<int> n` by reference to change its content. Thus as `std::vector<std::vector<int>& n` otherwise you will just be modifying a copy. Also stop using `using namespace std;`

Comment: Please post a [mre] with a `main` that demonstrates your problem. BTW - the matrix that you posted is not squared as your `upper_triangle` assumes by setting both `rij` and `kolom` to `n.size()`.

Comment: You put `return result;` inside the outer loop. I think you meant it to be after both loops end.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it looks like the OP would like to get the new matrix as a return value, rather than modify the `n` argument. But anyway it should be passed by reference as you said (`const &` if no need to modify).

Comment: The copying is pointless when the matrix is passed by value – you can modify `n` and return it.

Comment: @wohlstad noted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have `return result;` in the wrong place. Like this

```
vector<vector <int>> upper_triangle(vector<vector <int>> n) {
    int rij = n.size();
    int kolom = n.size();
    vector<vector<int>> result = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < rij; i++) {
        ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

not this

```
vector<vector <int>> upper_triangle(vector<vector <int>> n) {
    int rij = n.size();
    int kolom = n.size();
    vector<vector<int>> result = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < rij; i++) {
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Of course the point of indenting code is to make errors like this easier to spot.